# Spring + JPA + Hibernate: why org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using hibernate 4.2.7.SP1 and see that it loads persistence context with `org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration` class.

I don't have any EJB and my application uses plain spring + JPA.

Is it ok?
How to specify something like JpaConfiguration?

Comment: According to documentation: _Deprecated. Direct usage of this class has never been supported. Instead, the application should obtain reference to the EntityManagerFactory as outlined in the JPA specification, section 7.3 Obtaining an Entity Manager Factory based on runtime environment. Additionally this class will be removed in Hibernate release 5.0 for the same reasoning outlined on Configuration due to move towards new SessionFactory building methodology. See HHH-6181 and HHH-6159 for details_. So I would suggest to take a look at the specs and those two issues for more details.

Comment: That's correct. But I am using 4.2.7.SP1 and haven't specified any special config. However all over the logs I do see org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration

Comment: Just ignore it. It will work and basically has nothing to do with EJBs. This is actually a known issue/bug in hibernate itself :).